# How to distinguish two strings 'ALARM' and 'ARM' when both of them contain the word 'ARM'

Tags: android

I am reading incomming sms's and and when the word ALARM comes i do a certain code, and when ARM comes i do something else. The incoming sms might contain more than just these words for ex. ABCDEF, ARM, ALARM. or ALARM, ABCDEF etc.
I want to check what words are contained in the message and trigger different parts of the code.

My problem is that the word ALARM contains 2 words. The ALARM and the ARM. And because i use the method 'contains' for string, if the word ALARM comes it triggers the ARM as well. 
Is there a way to distinguish this?

What i use is this:

```
if (messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().contains("ALARM")) {

                btnAlarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyles_highlight);
            } else {
                btnAlarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plainbuttonstyles);
            }

        if (messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().contains("ARM")) {
            btnArm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyles_highlight);
        } else {
            btnArm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plainbuttonstyles);
        }
```

I tried a few other methods apart from contains but i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a simple string comparison!

Comment: Why don't you check for "Alarm" and then "Arm" both at the same time, so if it's true for both then it's the word "Alarm", however if one of them is false then it's the word "Arm" ?

Comment: why not use `equals()` instead?

Comment: because the words might be in the middle of the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the message into a list of words, where a word is a sequence of letters not having another letter adjacent to it. A regular expression may be used for that:

```
String[] words = message.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
```

Then check if your keyword is contained in the word list. For example with:

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
if (wordList.contains("ALARM")) { ... }
if (wordList.contains("ARM")) { ... }
```

Comment: this worked for me m8. thank you. I didnt know about that split

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `equals()` method for comparision of String

Use this POC:

```
if (messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().equals("ALARM")) {

            btnAlarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyles_highlight);
        } else {
            btnAlarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plainbuttonstyles);
        }

    if (messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().equals("ARM")) {
        btnArm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonstyles_highlight);
    } else {
        btnArm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plainbuttonstyles);
    }
```

Comment: because the message might have more than one word in it

Answer (score 0):

```
    int alarmIndex = messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().indexOf("ALARM");
    int armIndex = messageList.get(0).getMessageContent().indexOf("ARM");

    if(alarmIndex != -1 && alarmIndex < armIndex) {
        // Contains ALARM
        ...
    }
    else if(armIndex != -1){
        // Contains ARM
        ...
    }
```